# Use mixins for two possible constructors in union type

Tags: typescript, mixins

I have two classes that have extended from an abstract class and each have different values assigned to the same variable (ex. name) as well as a bunch of other methods with different implementations. I don't know how convoluted this looks, but it's a vastly simplified version of the actual classes.

I've updated this post to not use protected properties due [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73898981/14165510) as I want to highlight other issues.

```
abstract class AsbtractClass<N extends "Matt" | "Tom", V extends 1 | 2> {
  public abstract attributeName(): N;
  public abstract attributeValue(): V;

  public name: N;
  public value: V;

  constructor() {
    this.name = this.attributeName();
    this.value = this.attributeValue();
  }
}

class Class1 extends AsbtractClass<"Matt", 1> {
  public _lastName = "Murdock";

  public attributeName() {
    return "Matt" as const;
  }
  public attributeValue() {
    return 1 as const;
  }

  public doSomethingWithValue() {
    return Math.random() + this.value
  }
}

class Class2 extends AsbtractClass<"Tom", 2> {
  public _lastName = "Smith";

  public attributeName() {
    return "Tom" as const;
  }
  public attributeValue() {
    return 2 as const;
  }

  public doSomethingWithValue() {
   return Math.random() + this.value + 2
  }
}
```

It turns out that I now have converging, identical functionality that need to apply to both classes and need to after each method runs, and I need to know the possible classes I'm extending. [In this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Directed_acyclic_graph.svg) from [this page on mixins](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know/) that has gone way over my head, it's as if the abstract class is B, the Class1 is C, Class2 is D and what I want to do is converge functionality in E.

However, it seems I can't just do an union type from their constructors.

```
type GenericConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type Class1Constructor = GenericConstructor<Class1>;
type Class2Constructor = GenericConstructor<Class2>;

export function ExtendedClassOneOrTheOther<
  TBase extends Class1Constructor | Class2Constructor
>(Base: TBase) {
  return class ExtendedClass extends Base {
    public lastName() {
      return this._lastName;
    }

    public doSomethingWithValue() {
      const newValue = super.doSomethingWithValue()
      return newValue * 100
    }
  };
}
```

I get a `Property '_lastName' does not exist on type 'ExtendedClass'. Did you mean 'lastName'?(2551)`error, and `super` is typed as `any`. I'm at a loss, since I only find information on applying a mixin when the TBase generic is a single possible constructor, not two possible ones that have things in common. Even the aforementioned linked ['All you need to know'](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know/) page seems to only talk about a constructor that has already implemented something from a previous mixin, but I don't have any previous mixins, just classes. I may be wrong on if the article would help with that, since it's all new information. But I'm still stumped.

Here's a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB5zVw). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have private/protected methods on an exported, dynamically created class expression if you're emitting declaration files, mixins don't really have anything to do with it (other than that they use dynamically created classes in their implementation).

```ts
const foo = () => class Foo { // Error!
  private bar(): number {
    return 5;
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBKFA+GwA2AhhBDAGKIwDeAUDDAA4BOAlgG6FQCmMARoU0wAuGGACuAW15cm1OvRhMuUMUzAwArAG55AXxq6dQA)

Reason being that there's no way to capture this type currently in a `.d.ts` file. If you don't need to emit declaration files, you can IIRC get rid of the error simply by putting noEmit in your tsconfig.

See also [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30355) for discussion.

Comment: Got it! 

Ok, so let's say I replace all properties as public. This was the blocking error I got in my codebase. Why I get the error `Property '_lastName' does not exist on type 'ExtendedClass'. Did you mean 'lastName'? Even though it knows I either extend Class1Constructor or Class2Constructor, both of which have _lastName property.

https://shorturl.at/cds39

Comment: I don't get the example, since ._lastName was not declared even as protected on `Foo`.

Also it's my fault for editing my comment too late. https://shorturl.at/cds39 shows how ._lastName is not valid even when public. And I also noticed that super.doSomethingWithValue() is any. In fact, super.aRandomMethod or super.aRandomProperty is also any. It doesnt seem it gets any inference from these even if both classes have them.

Comment: IDK man. I think I was off base about the protected properties anyway. I'll leave this for now, but maybe can get back to it